# get highest attribute number in jquery and ecmascript6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

trying to get the max value for all selects with the same data attribute. but receiving the error

> {   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function",
>   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 37,   "colno":
>   34 }

please run  snippet below I would like it to console out 3 as that is the highest responsegroupnumber with a question.id of 1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let question = {
    Id: 1
  };

  let responseGroupNumber = Math.max(...$(`select[data-questionid = ${question.Id}]`)
    .map(x => $(x)
      .attr('data-responsegroupnumber')));

  console.log(responseGroupNumber);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="1">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>


<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="2">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>

<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="3">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is this error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) function before mapping :

If you don't, you'll be using jQuery [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method instead of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let question = {
    Id: 1
  };
  
  let responseGroupNumber = Math.max(...$(`select[data-questionid = ${question.Id}]`).get().map(x => $(x).attr('data-responsegroupnumber')));
  console.log(responseGroupNumber);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="1">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>


<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="2">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>

<select data-questionid="1" data-responsegroupnumber="3">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think jQuery objects have the `.map()` function

Comment: @Pointy I know, I just figured OP wanted to use `Array#map`. Both methods are valid if OP uses them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible implementation could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 let question = {
   Id: 1
 };

 var selects = $(`select[data-questionid=${question.Id}]`).toArray();
 var dataGroupNumber = selects.map(select => ($(select).attr('data- 
   responsegroupnumber')));

let responseGroupNumber = Math.max.apply(null, dataGroupNumber);
console.log(responseGroupNumber);
});
```

Math.max.apply(null, dataGroupNumber) instead of spread the array inside the Math.max( ... );